# what is the test attribute?

Tags: jsp, jstl

In the jstl code :

```
<c:if test="${name eq 'OS'}">
            <i>Inside the if statement</i>
        </c:if>
```

what does the attribute `test` denote ?

Comment: Have you even *tried* reading the documentation?  A tutorial?  A quick reference?  Anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*`test`* is a test condition that determines whether or not body content should be processed.

Like :`${name eq 'OS'}` will return true if the condition is true and otherwise false.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by denote?It stands for if statement like this
`if(name.equals('OS'))`